# angular 11 load component into a different router-outlet than main router-outlet

Tags: angular, web, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have a main router-outlet in the app.component.html to load the main page (layout). I created a separated layout module, routing and component to be that main page, the purpose is to allow this layout be re-designed in any moment:

[image]

The layout.component.html has this:

```
<div class="layout__container">
   <div class="layout__container__sidebar">
       <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
   </div>
   <div class="layout__container__content">
       <div class="layout__container__content-header">
           <div class="header-brand">
               <span>My App</span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="layout__container__content-body">
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app-nav-menu component provides the menu item options with routerLinks and paths for loading the components (content) into the right side of the layout (router-outlet), however when clicking any option, the component is loading full page since is using the main router-outlet from the app.component.html.

This is the app.routing.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from '@modules/layout/layout.component';

import { CanActivateIdentityGuard } from './guards/can-activate-identity.guard';

/**
*  Handle the global routing at module level.
*  Each module handle its own routing for components.
*/
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'identity', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/identity/identity.module').then(m => m.IdentityModule) 
  },
  {
    path: '',
    // If root path is specified, check whether user is authenticated through this guard, enabling the module indicated by loadchildren.
    canActivate: [ CanActivateIdentityGuard ],
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/layout/layout.module').then(m => m.LayoutModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**', // Route doesn't exist, will route for a 404 page if redirecting is not set
    redirectTo: '/home'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  // forRoot: register the top-level routes that should be imported only once by the root module of the application.
  // This method will return the routing module with providers declared if any.
  // forChild: register nested routes in a lazy-loaded module
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is the layout.routing.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '@modules/home/home.component';

/**
*  Handle the Navigation Menu routing for the application.
*  The main skeleton of the app is the Layout Component which loads NavMenu and main home components.
*  The home page is Home Component.
*/
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

and ... layout.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutRoutingModule } from './layout.routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ToolsModule } from '../tools/tools.module';
import { TimerSessionService } from '@services/timer-session.service';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '@modules/home/home.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from 'app/components/nav-menu/nav-menu.component';

/**
*  Application Modules and Components are loaded by SharedModule.
*/

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, NavMenuComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ToolsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TimerSessionService
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

Comment: Could you share your routing modules? Or create a minimal reproducible example on something like stackblitz?

Comment: I edited the question to add the required code.

Comment: I'm having trouble to reproduce the issue. Your code seems fine overall. 
Could you try to play with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdnybq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html and see if you can reproduce it?

If you have a parent `router-outlet` and a child `router-outlet`, the parent will only change when the parent route is modified. So perhaps you have a component loaded in both places resulting in it being loaded in the parent instead of the child router-outlet or something among those lines.

Comment: Akirus, in some way you were right, some components were loaded in a module that was referenced in the main router module so was he cause was redirecting in the parent router-outlet, the link you provided has a sample of that.

Comment: Glad it helped :)